# Json.net deserialize complex object with concurrent collection in composition

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a class like this:

```
public class ComplexClass
{
    public ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass> _simpleClassObjects;
}
```

When i serialize this class, it works. But when i try to deserialize

```
public static ComplexClass LoadComplexClass()
    {
        ComplexClass persistedComplexClass;
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(File.Open(jsonFilePath, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            persistedComplexClass = (ComplexClass) JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize(stream, typeof(ComplexClass));
        }
        return persistedComplexClass;
    }
```

it throws the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1[LabML.Model.Point]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[LabML.Model.Point]'.

This root cause of this exception is that the `ConcurrentBag<T>` doesn't implements generic `ICollection<T>`, only non-generic `ICollection`.

How to resolve this using Json.Net? (I've searched a while for this, but only what i found is about mapping an `ICollection<T>` to `ConcurrentCollection` not in Complex Classes.

Comment: Take a look at custom converters: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

As of Release 10.0.3, Json.NET claims to correctly serialize `ConcurrentBag<T>`.  According to the [release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.3):

- Fix - Fixed serializing ConcurrentStack/Queue/Bag

**Original Answer**

As you surmise, the problem is that [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable<T>` but not `ICollection<T>` so Json.NET does not know how to add items to it and treats it as a read-only collection.  While `ConcurrentBag<T>` does have a [parameterized constructor taking an input collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381771(v=vs.110).aspx), Json.NET will not use that constructor because it also, internally, has  [`[OnSerializing]`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs,9c42501178fbff04) and [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs,159c6314bf80602f) callbacks.  Json.NET will not use a parameterized constructor when these callbacks are present, instead throwing an exception

```
Cannot call OnSerializing on an array or readonly list, or list created from a non-default constructor: System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1[]
```

Thus it is necessary to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `ConcurrentBag<T>`:

```
public class ConcurrentBagConverter : ConcurrentBagConverterBase
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.GetConcurrentBagItemType() != null;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            var itemType = objectType.GetConcurrentBagItemType();
            var method = GetType().GetMethod("ReadJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { objectType, itemType });
            return genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { reader, objectType, itemType, existingValue, serializer });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            // Wrap the TargetInvocationException in a JsonSerializationException
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Failed to deserialize " + objectType, ex);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var objectType = value.GetType();
        try
        {
            var itemType = objectType.GetConcurrentBagItemType();
            var method = GetType().GetMethod("WriteJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { objectType, itemType });
            genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { writer, value, serializer });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            // Wrap the TargetInvocationException in a JsonSerializationException
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Failed to serialize " + objectType, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class ConcurrentBagConverter<TItem> : ConcurrentBagConverterBase
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ConcurrentBagConverter<TItem>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return ReadJsonGeneric<ConcurrentBag<TItem>, TItem>(reader, objectType, typeof(TItem), existingValue, serializer);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        WriteJsonGeneric<ConcurrentBag<TItem>, TItem>(writer, value, serializer);
    }
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836648/json-net-deserialize-complex-object-with-concurrent-collection-in-composition
public abstract class ConcurrentBagConverterBase : JsonConverter
{
    protected TConcurrentBag ReadJsonGeneric<TConcurrentBag, TItem>(JsonReader reader, Type collectionType, Type itemType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        where TConcurrentBag : ConcurrentBag<TItem>
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Expected {0}, encountered {1} at path {2}", JsonToken.StartArray, reader.TokenType, reader.Path));
        var collection = existingValue as TConcurrentBag ?? (TConcurrentBag)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(collectionType).DefaultCreator();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return collection;
                default:
                    collection.Add((TItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader, itemType));
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Should not come here.
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unclosed array at path: " + reader.Path);
    }

    protected void WriteJsonGeneric<TConcurrentBag, TItem>(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        where TConcurrentBag : ConcurrentBag<TItem>
    {
        // Snapshot the bag as an array and serialize the array.
        var array = ((TConcurrentBag)value).ToArray();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, array);
    }
}

internal static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static Type GetConcurrentBagItemType(this Type objectType)
    {
        while (objectType != null)
        {
            if (objectType.IsGenericType
                && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ConcurrentBag<>))
            {
                return objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
            objectType = objectType.BaseType;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class ConcurrentBagContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonArrayContract CreateArrayContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);

        var concurrentItemType = objectType.GetConcurrentBagItemType();
        if (concurrentItemType != null)
        {
            if (contract.Converter == null)
                contract.Converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConcurrentBagConverter<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { concurrentItemType }));
        }

        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then, apply the generic version to your specific field as follows:

```
public class ComplexClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConcurrentBagConverter<SimpleClass>))]
    public ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass> _simpleClassObjects;
}
```

Or, apply a universal version globally for all `ConcurrentBag<T>` for any `T` using the following settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ConcurrentBagConverter() },
};
```

Alternatively a custom contract resolver could be used, which might have slightly better performance than using the universal converter:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new ConcurrentBagContractResolver(),
};
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdeLnU).

That being said, the above only work if the `ConcurrentBag<T>` property or field is read/write.  If the member is read-only then I have found that Json.NET 9.0.1 will skip deserialization *even if a converter is present* because it infers that the collection member and contents are both read-only.  (This may be a bug in [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.CalculatePropertyDetails()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L1047).)

As a workaround, you could make the property be privately settable, and mark it with `[JsonProperty]`:

```
public class ComplexClass
{
    ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass> m_simpleClassObjects = new ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass>();

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConcurrentBagConverter<SimpleClass>))]
    [JsonProperty]
    public ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass> _simpleClassObjects { get { return m_simpleClassObjects; } private set { m_simpleClassObjects = value; } }
}
```

Or use a surrogate array property, thereby eliminating the need for any sort of converter:

```
public class ComplexClass
{
    readonly ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass> m_simpleClassObjects = new ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass>();

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass> _simpleClassObjects { get { return m_simpleClassObjects; } }

    [JsonProperty("_simpleClassObjects")]
    SimpleClass[] _simpleClassObjectsArray
    {
        get
        {
            return _simpleClassObjects.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            foreach (var item in value)
                _simpleClassObjects.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: helped a lot in understanding, advanced and good answer. Thanks!